# Adding listeners to firebase database nodes from onChildAdded

Tags: android, json, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my database, I maintain a list of IDs that point to different objects under another node in the database. For example, there is a node "users" and each child has an ID. I've stored the IDs under another node "friends". In my android app, how would I go about adding event listeners to the child nodes (users), without adding multiple event listeners?

Database Example:

```
{
  "friends" : 
  {
    "friend1" : "user1",
    "friend2" : "user2"
  },
  "users" : 
  {
    "user1" : 
    {
      "last" : "doe",
      "name" : "john"
    },
    "user2" : 
    {
      "last" : "response",
      "name" : "jason"
    },
    "user3" : 
    {
      "last" : "shei",
      "name" : "sue"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you upload the screenshot of firebase database sample so it would be helpful to reply your question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation yet to upload images :/

Comment: Don't upload images of text, it's a waste of good pixels. Instead, add the actual JSON as text to your question. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: But to load data, you will need a listener on the location of that data. What's your concern for adding multiple listeners?

Comment: I've added a simple example of the database. I want to attach listeners to all 
"user" objects that have their id in the "friends" object. Ideally I would cycle through "friends" and add listeners but that would cause duplicate listeners on the user objects because onChildAdded runs for every existing child as well, when a new child is added.